# Chrome extension template with AngularDart

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart, angular-dart

Is there any boilerplate/template chrome extension built with AngularDart?

Comment: I don't think there is much specific to Angular. If you get a Dart app running as Chrome extension you will also get it running with AngularDart. I had troubles (still unsolved) with `port.postMessage()`, `port.onMessage()`, `sendResponse()` but that has nothing to do with Angular.